# Create datagridviews with dynamic hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, datagridview

I would need to create a dynamic gridview, the number of columns are variable.
I try to explain myself better ..

I have to create a table that contains a column for each hotel and in the rows the days of the month with the relative people booked for each hotel.
EXAMPLE:

- |DAY| HOTEL 1 | HOTEL 2|
- |2021-09-01| 100| 90|
- |2021-09-02| 102| 92|

For each user I have saved in the db the hotels that he can view, so I have to create a datagridview with columns that are created dynamically.
I would like to display a hyperlink in the number of people booked so that if you click on it, it opens a page with the details of the reservation, passing the data of the day and the hotel

Since the ID and DAY columns will always be there, I thought not to create them dynamically, but to write them in the code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DFDFDF" />
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#3a4f63"  HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="#C6C3C6"></PagerStyle>                        
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                                ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="giorno" HeaderText="Giorno" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                                ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            

                         </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I initialize my DataTable dt with the first columns id and day

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
 dt.Columns.Add("id")
 dt.Columns.Add("day")
```

in the query that finds the hotels to display, I add the hyperlink columns to the datagridview

```
dt.Columns.Add(dr("hotel"))

Dim tfield As New HyperLinkField()
tfield.HeaderText = dr("hotel")
tfield.NavigateUrl = "info_booking.aspx?ID={0}"
tfield.Text = "11" 'IF I OMIT THE LINE, I DO NOT DISPLAY ANYTHING

GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield)
```

now I do a loop where I populate the lines with hotels and reservations and add the data to the DataTable as follows

```
...
dt.Rows.Add("1", "01/07/2021", "100", "90")
dt.Rows.Add("2", "02/07/2021", "102", "92")
...
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

I have the following problem, if I omit the line

```
tfield.Text = "11" 'IF I OMIT THE LINE, I DO NOT DISPLAY ANYTHING
```

the datagridview is composed as follows

- |DAY| HOTEL 1 | HOTEL 2|
- |2021-09-01|  |  |
- |2021-09-02|  |  |

If, on the other hand, I write the line and assign any value, for example 11, I display 11 on all lines, that is

- |DAY| HOTEL 1 | HOTEL 2|
- |2021-09-01| 11 | 11 |
- |2021-09-02| 11 | 11 |

I would like to understand how to modify the text and the parameters to be passed in the hyperlink of each single row and column.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I've change hyperlink to bounfield and than I create a hyperlink in event RowDataBound. So I've delete this code:

```
Dim tfield As New HyperLinkField()
tfield.HeaderText = dr("hotel")
tfield.NavigateUrl = "info_booking.aspx?ID={0}"
tfield.Text = "11" 'IF I OMIT THE LINE, I DO NOT DISPLAY ANYTHING
```

and write this code:

```
Dim bfield As BoundField = New BoundField()
 bfield.HeaderText = dr("hotel")
 bfield.DataField = "id_" & dr("hotel")
 GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield)
```

than I add row in this hand:

```
Row("id") = "2"
 Row("giorno") = "02/07/2021"
 Row("id_Hotel 1") = "102"
 Row("id_Hotel 2") = "103"

 dt.Rows.Add(Row)
```

and I've create event datarowbound

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            For i = 0 To i_rif
                Dim hp As HyperLink = New HyperLink()
                hp.Text = e.Row.Cells(i + 2).Text
                hp.Target = "_blank"
                hp.NavigateUrl = "~/Dettaglio_rifugio_giorno.aspx?data=" & e.Row.Cells(1).Text & "&amp;id_rifugio=" & arr_rif(i)
                e.Row.Cells(i + 2).Controls.Add(hp)
            Next

        End If

    End Sub
```

After 1 week I've found a solution!

Hope this post can help someone.

Bye